# Laravel: How to clear cache with Bash .sh script

Tags: laravel, bash, caching

Using Windows.
I want to write and call a .sh script which will contain:

```
ssh root@api.*name*.com
cd /var/www/api.*name*.com
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan responsecache:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

At the moment it'll just login but not navigate to the directory or run the php artisan parts.
I will then schedule this to run with windows task scheduler.

Comment: Please format your code properly (fixed font, one statement per line).

Comment: Might want to take a look into [Laravel Envoy](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/envoy)

Answer (score 0):

You can call Artisan command from code (controller, model etc). For example:

```
 Artisan::call("cache:clear");
```